# Google Chrome shortcut for opening link on new tab?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a google chrome shortcut for opening a link on a new tab so we don't have to right-clivk? I'm looking at something like ctrl+click link and then page will open on a new tab similar to the way we can shift+click link to open page in a new window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - Google Chrome acts in just the way you describe.  Ctrl + clicking a link will open it in a new tab.

Comment: Is there a shortcut to open a new tab and also navigate to it? Ctrl+Click opens it in the background.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Click opens in new tab and brings it to foreground.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome opens links in a new tab like any other browser:

- by pressing the middle mouse button
- by holding CTRL while left-clicking

Answer (score 0):

The same question has been answered here:
[Google Chrome: Is there a keyboard shortcut to open a link in a new tab?](https://superuser.com/questions/195419/google-chrome-is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-open-a-link-in-a-new-tab?rq=1)

You can do that with Ctrl + Enter.